# Redirect URLs using Redirect component or htaccess

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, redirect

In Joomla 3.4 want to redirect this page:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/component/k2/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html
```

To this:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html
```

Using `Compontent - > Redirect`, I added the following redirect:

```
/component/k2/1422-como-i...ética-na-sua-empresa.html
```

Redirect to:

https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/1422-como-i...%C3%A9tica-na-sua-empresa.html

But this did not work.

Then I added in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.portal-gestao.com
RewriteRule ^component/k2/(.*)$ https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/$1
```

But this also doesn't work.

Help anyone?

Comment: "RewriteRule ^/component/k2/(.*)$ /item/$1", maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Just enter the url you want to rewrite in the browser and after that directly check the rewrite component of joomla. If its active the link appear and you can set a redirect location.

Hit up the adress should show it in redirect-component as 404 page by date.

Answer (score 0):

Component -> Redirect expects you to enter the full urls for both the source and the destination.