# Joomla redirect with HTTP Status Code (redirect component vs .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, seo, redirect

First of all, this is not the same question as can be found here: [(Redirect URLs using Redirect component or .htaccess)](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10338/redirect-urls-using-redirect-component-or-htaccess).

What I want to know is what HTTP Status Code (for e.g. 301, 302, 303, etc...) is by default for the Joomla's redirect component, or not being used at all?

I have read the official documentation [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Components_Redirect_Manager) but with no specific explanation about the matter.

Another doc here:[Creating_301_redirects](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_301_redirects) suggests only a few details.

If SEO is the main concern, then the Joomla's redirect component seems to be unusable.

Comment: I can recommend to use .htaccess redirect, I have 3 very large sites and com_redirect never worked 100% correctly his job. What I know default redirect has 301 code.

Comment: I am not sure of the answer, but here is a good tool that might help: http://redirectcheck.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

The redirect manager uses 301 redirects by default, unless you set the header type in the [advanced mode](http://www.itoctopus.com/the-advanced-mode-in-joomlas-redirect-manager-a-mystery-unveiled)

Note: Always keep in mind that Joomla's redirect manager only works when the URL you are trying to redirect form returns a 404 error code and is caught by the Joomla environment.